‹‹ fait aux mystères ›› : meaning of ‹‹ aux ››
I came across this sentence in a story by Maupassant:

J'appartiens à la vieille race naïve accoutumée à ne pas comprendre, à ne pas chercher, à ne pas savoir, faite aux mystères environnants et qui se refuse à la simple et nette vérité.

I am not sure how to interpret the preposition after 'faite'. What, in this case, would be the equivalent preposition in English?

Faite means "fashioned" here, synonymous with façonnée.

Fait à ici veut dire ici habitué à. In English I expect you could use the adjective accustomed which would lead to using the preposition to.
Fait à in the TLF C.2 :

Fait à + subst. déterminé ou inf. Accoutumé, entraîné, exercé à. Fait au climat, aux habitudes, à un genre de vie. Son grand esprit positif et rigoureux, si peu fait à se payer d'abstractions (Sainte-Beuve, Port-Royal,t. 3, 1848, p. 313).− Donnez-moi qui vous voudrez, Monsieur le Directeur, mais un homme fait à ce travail et qu'il ne me soit pas nécessaire de reprendre à l'A.B.C. (Duhamel, Combat ombres,1939, p. 18).


You could just say: followed by to. If, however, you leave it as was, you need to using and not to use.
